# Is there any way to know if outlook is installed on users system, using HTML & javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, outlook

I want to check if user has outlook application installed just by using a simple HTML page with javascript.
Is this possible?

NOTE: This should also work on google chrome. ActiveXObject does'nt work on Google chrome

Regards,

Arif

Comment: ask the user with a yes or no : )

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way for a webpage to sniff out what is installed (with the occasional exception of browser plugins) on a visitor's system.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for the confirmation